# October Partials Folders

Tags: partials, octobercms

How we create the folder structure like on this screenshot?
When I click "add" it's a file...
Thank you.

[OctoberCMS-partials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1gdA.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Click add  > File name

```
pages-test/test.htm
```

> Save

It allows you to create a file 'test.htm' inside of 'pages-test' folder on partials.